# webMethods business rules: How to create a decision table that depends on another decision table

Tags: rule-engine, webmethods

I am using the native rule engine of webMethods (wm Business rule) to create complex rule. I need to create a decision table that depends on the result of another decision table. As shown in the graphic below, 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out how to do it.

The idea is to put both decision tables into the same rule set. Then running the rule set by providing var1, var2, param1 and param2

The rule engine is going to infer the result for the first decision table into the second one.

NB. the name of the result of the first table has to be the same in the second table.